# HTML2PDF on internet explorer for SVG

Tags: pdf, web-frontend, html2pdf

I'm using eKoopmans [HTML2PDF on github](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf)

This is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/GoodJeans/yjrg4ukk/1/), my project involves using SVG and I need to display a PDF page with svg on all browsers.

Currently the SVG is not showing on Internet Explorer if you open the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/GoodJeans/yjrg4ukk/1/) on IE.
is there a way to fix this?

```html
<div id="element-to-print">
SVG won't work on internet explorer, only google chrome
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

</div>
```